# Unable to start sonarqube on mac os catalina

Tags: sonarqube, macos-catalina

I am trying to start sonarqube server on Mac. 
Followed the steps mentioned at [Get Started in Two Minutes Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/get-started-2-minutes/).
Got access issue which was fixed by [Access Issue](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-cannot-start-once-updated-to-macos-catalina-error-as-wrapper-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified/16439/2).

Update 1 : Extracted the zip file in Downloads folder (tried 7.0 and 8.0 version of sonar qube).

Again when tried following command in mentioned directory.

```
sh sonar.sh console
```

Got following error

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM... 
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | Error: Could not find or load main class org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Moved the extracted folder to a current_user/Document and again tried the mentioned steps. Able to run sonar qube :).

Answer (score 7):

Go to `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy` `General` tab after running your code. Then `allow anyway` and try again. You will see `open` button on the modal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. go to conf (cd sonarqube-8.0\ 2/conf)
2. edit your ( vi wrapper.conf)
3. change the java path to JDK (your local java path)- wrapper.java.command=**/usr/bin/java** (local path of java)

try to start the sonar by using  **./sonar.sh start**

if it fails please go to logs folder which is one level down to bin(cd ..) and share the logs from sonar.log and es.log

Answer (score 0):

Also, check web.log

In my case, I had to change the port because port 9000 was already in use.

Also, I had to use Java 11 instead of Java 8